# Why does my arcpy script's da.UpdateCursor get slower the longer it runs?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, python-3, pycharm

I have a layer containing pedestrian crosswalks (line features), and two layers containing street data: street segments (line features) and street nodes (point features). Every street segment has a node at either end, with its own Node ID. Most of the crosswalks cross one or two street segments. For each point at which a crosswalk crosses a street segment, I'm trying to determine which node ID is closest. I'm using this method:

1. Generate the intersection points between the crosswalks and the street segments.
2. At each of those points, split the street segment.
3. Spatially join the node ID to each of the two (now split) street segments.
4. Find the shorter of the two segments.
5. Return the node ID of that shorter segment.

Because a street segment can have many crosswalks, steps 2-5 have to be done for each crosswalk/segment intersection point individually. Part of my script is below, it takes the output of step 1 above and runs a `da.UpdateCursor` to do steps 2-5 for each crosswalk/segment intersection point. The script works, it generates the correct output.

I'm writing and running the script in PyCharm, using the Python 3 environment that comes with ArcGIS Pro. The problem is that the longer it runs, the slower it gets. It starts out processing one row in 0.7 seconds. After 1000 records, it's up to 4 seconds, getting slower and slower until I stop it manually. Stopping and restarting the script in PyCharm resets the performance.

I've read that nesting a `da.SearchCursor` inside another cursor can cause this progressive slowdown, and I'm using a nested cursor here, but I'm not clear how that would be causing the slowdown in my case: it's only ever searching through 2 records and I'm deleting the SearchCursor after each iteration of the UpdateCursor.

A few other things:

- I have turned off logging using `arcpy.SetLogHistory(False)`.
- PyCharm's RAM and CPU usage remain about the same throughout: about 700MB of RAM used and ~25% of the CPU, with 6GB RAM remaining free on the PC and > 30% of CPU capacity remaining. I've also tried running the script in IDLE and Spyder with the same result, so it doesn't seem specific to the IDE.
- Temporary data is using the `memory\` workspace. The datasets that are on disk are on a solid-state drive.

```python
# seg_split_at_crosswalk, seg_split_with_nodes are feature classes in the "memory\" workspace.
# segment_fc, node_fc are existing data on disk.
# crosswalk_seg_crossings is a point layer of the intersections between crosswalks and segments, created earlier in the script.

# for each crossing point, find closest node which is on the segment crossed, and update row with NODE_ID
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(crosswalk_seg_crossings,["SEG_ID", "SHAPE@", "NODE_ID", "OBJECTID"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[2] is not None:
            continue
        elif row[2] is None:
            loop_start_time = time.time()
            sql = "SEG_ID = " + str(row[0])
            segment = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(segment_fc, "NEW_SELECTION", sql)
            arcpy.management.SplitLineAtPoint(segment, row[1], seg_split_at_crosswalk)
            arcpy.analysis.SpatialJoin(seg_split_at_crosswalk, node_fc, seg_split_with_nodes)

            # select shortest split seg
            dist_to_nodes = dict([(searchRow[0], searchRow[1]) for searchRow in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(seg_split_with_nodes,["NODE_ID", "SHAPE@LENGTH"])])
            row[2] = (min(dist_to_nodes, key=dist_to_nodes.get))
            cursor.updateRow(row)

            # print stats
            loop_execution_time = (time.time() - loop_start_time)
            print(sql, "|", row[2], "|", row[3], "|", loop_execution_time)

            # delete temp data
            arcpy.management.Delete(seg_split_at_crosswalk)
            arcpy.management.Delete(seg_split_with_nodes)
            del dist_to_nodes
            del loop_execution_time
            del loop_start_time
            del sql
            del row
```

Comment: @BERA Thanks, I just tried that (added a where clause to the cursor parameters, removed the if/elif statements) and strangely the performance degrades even faster: it only takes about 200 records for the execution time to get above 4 seconds per row.

Comment: I'd use geometry method to find location of intersection point on line.

Comment: It is called measureOnLine

Comment: I too have observed the slowing down on long run times and not necessarily with an update cursor. Try turning off history logging? Also try writing temporary datasets to in memory workspace.

Comment: @FelixIP What operation would you use measureOnLine for here? The intersect operation is only done once, before the cursor runs (the cursor operates on the output from that step), so I don't think that could be causing the slowdown in the cursor. However, each street segment does already have the Node ID of the FNODE and TNODE (the nodes at the beginning and end of the segment), so it looks like I could use measureOnLine instead of splitting the line: if the output of measureOnLine is less than half the length of the segment, the FNODE is closest, otherwise the TNODE is.

Comment: @Hornbydd I'm actually doing both of those things already, they don't appear in the code snippet though. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I'd  also create a dictionary of line shapes oid:shape if it fits into memory, the rest should be fast, although some 50 times slower than in ArcView 3

Comment: @Hornbydd How have you worked around these slowdowns when you've had them? Restart the script? That's what I did, and it allowed me to get my output, but I'm going to be updating this dataset periodically so I was hoping to get it running efficiently without human intervention.

Comment: Are you able to test your script from IDLE to see whether the performance degradation may be PyCharm rather than Python or ArcPy related?

Comment: @PolyGeo I'll try that. I had written a different script in Python 2.7 to do a similar job months ago, I ran that one in PyScripter and had the same problem of it slowing down over time, so I assumed it was my code and not related to the IDE. I'll give it a try though.

Comment: I'm convinced there is "something" getting progressively larger, possibly outside our control that may not be exposed by `arcpy` so we observed this slowing down. To combat this I try to make code use as input a FeatureLayer (not FeatureClass) which support selections. Cursors use selections on layers if they exist. So its relatively trivial to say select 0-999 let the code run accepting some slow down then you select 1000-1999 etc... This does mean I tend to run my code as a tool script in ArcMap so I can access the layer with a selection.